# Problem with View sorting ArrayAdapter several times

Tags: android, sorting, refresh, android-arrayadapter

I have a problem with this code. I modify the content of ArrayAdapter and ordered as an argument to the object containing the array. The problem is that modify the view (is a listview) with different things, icons, change the background etc. The fact is that by making the sort seems to mix the properties of some views. For example, the background that has spread to another one because of moving and things like:

```
public class IconLVAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Datos> {

        private List<Datos> objetos;
        private boolean online;

        public IconLVAdapterBuses(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<Datos> objetos, boolean online) {
                super(context, textViewResourceId, objetos);
                this.objetos = objetos;
                this.online = online;
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View v = convertView;
                if (v == null) {
                    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    v = vi.inflate(R.layout.rowlist, null);
                }
                Datos o = objetos.get(position);
                if (o != null) {

                        TextView tvNum = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.num);

                        if (o.getpOrigen()==null && tvNum!= null)
                            tvNum.setText(o.getnum());
                        else{
                                       ************** omitido **************
                        }

                }
                return v;
        }



        public void refreshArray(){
            this.sort(new Comparator<Datos>() {
                public int compare(Datos object1, Datos object2) {
                    return object1.compareTo(object2);
                };
            });
            this.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to call http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#invalidateViews() after you sorted the adapter?

Comment: Not work. I tried this calling first to sort of arrayadapter, after call invateViews of the ListView and alfter notifyDataSetChanged of arrayadapter.